# ¿Cómo se dice, “a caso” o “acaso”?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, adverbios, deletreo

En español, ¿cuál de las dos siguientes es la forma correcta para hacer la pregunta?

- > ¿A caso estuviste ahí?
- > ¿Acaso estuviste ahí?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adverb expressing doubt should always be a single word: *acaso*. Here is the DRAE definition:

> acaso.
>
> (De caso).
>
> 1. m. Casualidad, suceso imprevisto.
> 2. adv. m. desus. Por casualidad, accidentalmente.
> 3. adv. duda Quizá, tal vez.
> 4. adv. neg. Ec. no (‖ indica la falta de lo significado por el verbo). Acaso he podido dormir.

Comment: Are there any sentences where *a caso* would be correct?

Comment: @jrdioko: no; the adverb expressing doubt always should be a single word (I've updated my answer to suppress any possible ambiguity). There's, however, an adverbial locution *a caso hecho* which means *intencionadamente*, but clearly this locution has a complete different meaning from the adverb *acaso*.

Comment: GonzaloMedina: I think this is what @jrdioko was asking.

Comment: There are very few cases where you will find "a caso", but it is perfectly possible, for example when talking about a "judicial case". You could say "ganamos nuestra buena reputación caso a caso / we won our good reputation case by case". Or you could say, "resulta que tenemos que trabajar a caso por persona / turns out we must work on a case per person".

Comment: Por favor, quien haya votado negativamente mi respuesta, ¿podría indicar la razón que motivó el voto negativo?